# linq statement if users.Claims contains claims equal to parameters (LINQ)

Tags: c#, .net, linq

My db table structure is

```
ClaimsTable
Id (int) UserId (FK) ClaimType (string) ClaimValue (string)
1        1           Role               Administrator
```

I'm not tracking claims from users side, so when I need users claim I load manually.

RIght now I have simple linq question but I cannot see way out from here
I'm loading users claims and I want to check does that claim match with one passed as an argument

```
public bool HasClaim(User user, string type, string value)
{         
     var claimsRepository = ... claimsrepository init ....

     var userClaims = claimsRepository.FindAll().Where(usr => usr.User == user).ToList();

     if (userClaims.Count() > 0)
     {
         // linq statement to select those claims which has type and value 
         // equal to method parameters

         bool containsClaim = ?????
         if (containsClaim == true)
             return true;
     }
     return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for:

```
return claimsRepository.FindAll().Any(user => user.User == user &&
                                       user.ClaimType == type &&
                                       user.ClaimValue == value);
```